# Erro com relacionamento 1 para muitos, Power Tools não gera modelo

Tags: entity-framework

Quero fazer relacionamento um para muitos no EF onde um e somente Território possui várias regiões, mas ao analisar o modelo no Power Tools ele não reconhece.

**Região**

```
[Table("Regiao")]
public class Regiao
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0000}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long RegiaoID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Região")]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "O {0} deve ser de pelo menos {2} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório")]
    public string RegiaoDescricao { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FKTerritorioID")]
    public long TerritorioID { get; set; }
    public virtual Territorio Territorio { get; set; }
}
```

**Território**

```
[Table("Territorio")]
public class Territorio
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0000}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public long TerritorioID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Campo Obrigatório")]
    public string TerritorioDescricao { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Regiao> Regioes { get; set; }
}
```

**Contexto**

```
public class DbEmpresaContext : DbContext
{
    public DbEmpresaContext()
        : base("connDBEmpresaModelo")
    {            
    }

    public DbSet<Regiao> Regioes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Territorio> Territorios { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou fazer algumas pequenas mudanças em seu código.
Sua entidade **Territorio** ficaria assim:

```
[Table("Territorio")]
    public class Territorio
    {
        [Key]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0000}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public long TerritorioID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório")]
        public string TerritorioDescricao { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Regiao> Regioes { get; set; }
    }
```

Nesta entidade foi adicionado apenas a propriedade `virtual` para realizar o [Lazy Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/using-dbcontext-in-ef-4-1-part-6-loading-related-entities) (carregamento preguiçoso) das **Regiões**.

Já sua entidade **Regiao**, ficará desta forma:

```
[Table("Regiao")]
    public class Regiao
    {
        [Key]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0000}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long RegiaoID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Região")]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "O {0} deve ser de pelo menos {2} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 2)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório")]
        public string RegiaoDescricao { get; set; }

        public long FKTerritorioID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FKTerritorioID")]
        public virtual Territorio Territorio { get; set; }
    }
```

Já nesta entidade, foi realizado a alteração do nome de sua **foreing key** para **FKTerritorioID** para acompanhar sua **Annotation**.

Feito isso, basta chamar o seu modelo novamente.

### Criar Modelo .EDMX com EF

Para criar um modelo basta clicar com o botão direito do mouse em cima de sua classe **Context** (no exemplo acima seria a `DbEmpresaContext`). Após isso, navegue até Enitty Framework e após, View Entity Data Model, como mostra a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Fonte imagem: Microsoft.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/resources/tools)

Seguindo esse exemplo, seu modelo ficará como a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Randrade, o virtual tem que ficar na só coleção como nesse trecho do código que você mudou? public virtual Territorio Territorio { get; set; } Outra dúvida, já vi em códigos onde usam só os Data Annotations [Key] e [ForeignKey] para determinar os relacionamentos, não utilizam propriedades de navegação, isso está correto?

Comment: O `virtual`, a grosso modo, serve para retornar todas as regiões ao que o território possui, isso quando você buscar por ele.Sobre sua segunda dúvida, sim. Você não precisa utilizar **anottations** para isso. O EF gera automaticamente com base no nome das propriedades. Se quiser fazer uma pergunta sobre isso, ficarei feliz em explicar melhor.